# Form won't post select value in IE9

Tags: php, internet-explorer

All,
I've got the following page:
http://tinyurl.com/7lzr6qo

The original form code is:

```
<form id="dj_feedback" name="dj_feedback" action="../test-save-feedback" method="post">
<br>
<h2>How was the Event?</h2>
<hr>
<table><tr><td width="100px" valign="middle">
<b>Person<font color="#FF0000"> * </font></b>
</td><td valign="middle">
<select name="dj_name" id="dj_name">
<option value="original"></option>
<?php
$qrydj = "Select user_id, first_name, last_name from users where role='employee'";
$resultdj = mysql_query($qrydj);
while($resultsetdj = mysql_fetch_array($resultdj)){
?>
<option value="<?php echo $resultsetdj['user_id']; ?>"><?php echo $resultsetdj['first_name']." ".$resultsetdj['last_name']; ?></option>
<?php
}
?>
</select></td>
</tr>
</table>
<button class="submit" name="submit_feedback" value="submit_feedback">Get Paid!</button>
</form>
```

When I view the dropdown source it has a value on the select and then on my second page all I have is a simple echo statement to view what was passed like this:

```
<?php
session_start();
$user_id = $_POST['dj_name'];

echo "The user id is: ".$user_id;
?>
```

However, when I post this the value selected in the dropdown menu doesn't get passed. In other browsers this works perfectly fine however.

Does anyone have any idea why this isn't working properly?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you validated your html at http://validator.w3.org/?

Comment: try print_r($_POST); quite possibly i.e. not parsing the form as you expect. Also as red states run it through the w3 validator. The drop down cores not even display properly for me on safari.

Comment: @Peter It doesn't even seem to pass it along. Here is what print_r($_POST) gives: Array
 (
 [submit_feedback] => submit_feedback
 )

Comment: longshot but have you tried removing the table structure. Try it with purely the form alone. Or simply move the form tags directly before and after the select tags.

Comment: @redelman431 There are some errors but they are just simple CSS errors that I can change. That shouldn't alter how the form actually posts the data though.

Comment: @Peter I tried your suggestion and that still gives the same result.

Comment: is there any possibility that some of the javascript you are using is stripping the results?

Comment: Can you put your form back to how it was when you posted the question? The code is a bit messed up now.

Comment: @Peter No it shouldn't do that. I tried to change my button to an input type="submit" to see if that would change my results but it didn't and it still won't pass over the select statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to make IE know the button element is in fact submitting the form - Perhaps edit your button:

```
<button type="submit" class="submit" name="submit_feedback" value="submit_feedback">Get Paid!</button>
```

Note that the type attribute is a valid one: 
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_button.asp

and html5: 
http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tag_button.asp